# EF6 migration - FK to entity with composite Key error

Tags: entity-framework-6, composite-key

I have the following entities:

```
public class MeetingAttendee
    {
        public int MeetingId { get; set; }

        public Meeting Meeting { get; set; }

        public int UserId { get; set; }

        public User User { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<MeetingAttendanceEntry> MeetingAttendanceEntries { get; set; }
    }

public class MeetingAttendanceEntry
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public int MeetingId { get; set; }

        public Meeting Meeting { get; set; }

        public int MeetingAttendeeId { get; set; }

        public MeetingAttendee MeetingAttendee { get; set; }

        public AttendanceStatus AttendanceStatus { get; set; }
    }
```

The MeetingAttendee is set as:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MeetingAttendee>().HasKey(pk => new { pk.MeetingId, pk.UserId });
modelBuilder.Entity<MeetingAttendee>().HasRequired(o => o.User).WithMany(m => m.MeetingAttendees).HasForeignKey(fk => fk.UserId);
modelBuilder.Entity<MeetingAttendee>().HasRequired(o => o.Meeting).WithMany(m => m.Attendees).HasForeignKey(fk => fk.MeetingId);
```

And when I'm trying to add MeetingAttendanceEntry, I'm getting "**The number of properties in the Dependent and Principal Roles in a relationship constraint must be identical**" validation error.

I think is coming from the composite key, but everything I tried fails.

I tried from the parent entity:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MeetingAttendee>().HasMany(m => m.MeetingAttendanceEntries).WithRequired(e => e.MeetingAttendee).HasForeignKey(e => e.MeetingAttendeeId);
```

From the child:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MeetingAttendanceEntry>().HasRequired(e => e.MeetingAttendee).WithMany(m => m.MeetingAttendanceEntries).HasForeignKey(e => e.MeetingAttendeeId);
```

I tried adding the User and UserId to MeetingAttendanceEntry, and then setting it as FK as well:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MeetingAttendanceEntry>().HasRequired(e => e.User).WithMany().HasForeignKey(e => e.UserId);
```

but still no luck.
What I'm missing?

Comment: Ok got it.

modelBuilder.Entity<MeetingAttendanceEntry>()
                .HasRequired(e => e.MeetingAttendee)
                .WithMany(a => a.MeetingAttendanceEntries)
                .HasForeignKey(e => new { e.MeetingId, e.UserId });

Had to set the FK with the composite key.